# How to properly terminate Android application with live sockets

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, terminate

I implemented an Android Application with following features:

Application: `public class ApplicationGlobalAgent extends Application` contains:

- a MainActivity: to display GUI drawing -> and start other activities from it.
- a network ServerSocket and a client Socket: to send/receive data in duplex mode.

I want to terminate Application when MainActivity finish, I did as follow:

**In MainActivity extends Activity:**

```
@Override
public void finish()
{
    super.finish();

    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "finish and call app termination");

    //call the application to terminate
    getApplication().onTerminate(); 
}
```

**In ApplicationGlobalAgent extends Application:**

```
@Override
public void onTerminate()
{
    // do close ServerSocket and client Socket in networking threads
    mNetworkManager.DoStop();

    System.gc();

    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Terminated!");

    super.onTerminate(); //?? should be placed at the end of functions ??

    //totally kill this application process
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

**BUT results are:**

When have no network connection, the application terminates successfully, otherwise `"Terminated!"` is never printed until I close the network sockets at other side (who connected to the Android sockets).

So, How can I **force the application to properly and fully terminate** when exit the MainActivity with connecting network sockets?

Appreciate all your helps!

Comment: To be brutally honest, almost everything here is incorrect. I *strongly* encourage you to read through the documentation on [**the process lifecycle**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle) and [**the `Activity` lifecycle**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `@Override public void finish()`

You should be overriding `onDestroy` instead.

> `getApplication().onTerminate();`

*Never* call this directly.

> `System.gc();`

This really isn't necessary.

> `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Why are you having the application call `killProcess` on itself? You should let the Android runtime system kill processes for you.

> How can I force the application to properly and fully terminate when exist the `MainActivity` with connecting network sockets?

You don't need to worry about clean-up unless you have allocated resources that wouldn't be cleaned up when the Java process is killed by the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but your suggestion doesn't work (I've just tested). Actually, I have read many Stack-overflow threads about killing process. But my problem is that `application.onTerminate()` is only called by system proc manager when all child procs are finished, so application will wait for `mNetworkManager.DoStop()` to complete its network threads which close connecting and listening sockets.

I am intending to try to put:

`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`
in the top of onTerminate() to see how it works.

Comment: `onTerminate` is never called by the system except in emulated environments (read the [**docs**](http://bit.ly/fBd487). Again, you should not call either `killProcess` or `onTerminate`... you probably want to close the threads in the `Activity`'s `onDestroy` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right!
That why I try to explicitly call `app.onTerminate()` from main activity. Unfortunately, I have to implement network threads in global application to provide unique network utils for all the app's child activities. And ridiculously, deprecated methods of `Thread.stop() or Thread.destroy()` cannot be used for safe termination [I used `Thread.join(duration)` for my case]. I have changed `activity.finish()` to `onDestroy()` as you suggested but network server still not terminated.

Comment: If you need your network threads to work across all of your activities, it sounds like you should use a `Service` instead.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Actually I had thought about `Service` but my case is: I am writing an application with several simulations (networking and graphics). I broke them into separated activities while using the shared network connections. I had written a main activity to init others. But the network connections will not remain (as service), they have to be disposed and re-established every time I stop and re-start the global application. I tried to put `Process.killProcess(pid)` at the end of `onTerminate()` and seem to work quite well till now but not much satisfied for the stability of the solution.